# Threading. How does button click interrupt/influence program flow

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

My project is vb.net 2010 windows desktop form.
So far, single threaded (default).

If a SUBroutine has a for...next loop in it that is running, what happens if a buttonclick event is fired and within that event a variable is changed? Like: does program execution leave the loop that was running? Or does it continue to run while that variable is changed by the buttonclick event?

What I'm aiming for: 
If someone clicks the button, blnRequestStop is set to True.
Within that for...next loop, just before the "next" it checks blnRequestStop. If true then it will exit the "for" loop.

I'm guessing I need to use threads? Can anyone give me a simple example, please?

EDIT:
This code below *seems* to be working fine. But maybe you all see a problem?

```
If (btnProcess.Text = "Done!") Then
    End
ElseIf (btnProcess.Text = "IMPORT") Then
    bRequestStop = False
    t1 = New Thread(AddressOf ProcessDo)
    t1.Start()
Else
    t2 = New Thread(AddressOf MyInterrupt)
    t2.Start()
End If
```

Here is the short version of what ProcessDo and MyInterrupt do:

```
Private Sub ProcessDo()
    For each X in blahblah
        'do stuff (yes, includes interface)
        if (blnInterrupt) then exit For
    Next X
    End
End Sub

Private Sub MyInterrupt()
    blnInterrupt=true
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got a long-running task in the UI thread. Basically you shouldn't do that...

Comment: When you click a button all that happens is that the event is queued (not instantly run). Once your GUI thread (the thread that your `Form` was `new Form("form1")`'d on is available (idle), then it will read the queue and run your button click event.  Your GUI thread will not be idle until it exits the For...Next SUB (I'm used to C# otherwise I would have answered with code). look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably want to do the long-running task on a background thread. Here's a code sample including how you'd get the results back to the UI thread when you're done (otherwise you'll get errors about `Cross-thread operation not valid`).

`ThreadPool` is a nice way to do some work on a background thread. You could set `stopIt = True` in the button click event for the stop button.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
  Sub()
    For Each thing In things
      If stopIt Then Exit Sub
      'Do the stuff!
    Next

    'We're done, update UI
    Me.UpdateUI("All done!")
  End Sub)
```

To safely update the UI, you'll need to make sure you get back to the UI thread.

```
Public Sub UpdateUI(result As String)
  If Me.InvokeRequired() Then 
    'If we aren't on the UI thread, invoke this function on the UI thread
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() UpdateUI(result))
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'Update UI here
  lblResult.Text = result
End Sub
```

Comment: Please see edited original question. I'd like your ideas on my code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with directly using `Threads`, I'd say that typically people would recommend again using them. Using `ThreadPool` or a `BackgroundWorker` is usually better. It also depends on what `ProcessDo` and `MyInterrupt` are doing. If they're updating the UI at any point, they'll need to get back to the UI thread. Even if not, you might need to do `Thread.Join` (or something like that), to close them off when you're done, but again... I'm not familiar with `Thread`.

Answer (score -1):

Execution is '***stopped***' (in a way) until the Loop finishes him job, so yes, you need to multi-thread.

It it is not a very long operation where you need to update UI controls during the Loop then you just can use `Application.DoEvents` inside the loop to be able to use other controls as normally in the application when `FOR` loop is working, but I advise you that this will have a negative impact on UI performance, but if it's not a long duration loop then you maybe would consider to use `DoEvents` instead introduce into `multi-threading` it's just an alternative, not recommended but, you can use it.

PS: Forgive my English

Comment: never ever ever use DoEvents as part of normal program flow... ever. Use proper threading instead.

Comment: Calling this method causes the current thread to be suspended while all waiting window messages are processed. If a message causes an event to be triggered, then other areas of your application code may execute. This can cause your application to exhibit unexpected behaviors that are difficult to debug. If you perform operations or computations that take a long time, it is often preferable to perform those operations on a new thread. For more information about asynchronous programming, see Asynchronous Programming Model (APM).